# Chrome Extension Onclick() with Popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup, onclick, badge

I want to clean my notification (badge). When click onto the icon a popup should be opened at the same time, but it doesn't work.

It works with tab but I don't want to show on tab it should be on popup.

Here is the code;

```
var i = 1;

function updateIcon() {
    i=1;
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: ''});  
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup:"popup.html"});
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(updateIcon);
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[200, 0, 0, 100]});

window.setInterval(function() {
  chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:String(i)});
  i++;
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Your code will not work, `setPopup()` will not open your new popup for first time or in new window if popup is not in focus, BTW where is this code?

Comment: Code is in background.js , and it opens popup but it doesn't set badgetext, badge continues to growing;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Badge Text is growing because `Background Page` lives until extension is uninstalled or disabled.

So your code

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:String(i)});
  i++;
}, 4000);
```

keeps badge to continue growing.

Moreover, `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(updateIcon);` **will not work** second time!

What is you want to stop?

**P.S:** You are using two conflicting functionalities (`browserAction.onClicked` and `browserAction.setPopup`  together.

## EDIT 1

## Working Version

#### manifest.json

Registered Background Page and Browser Action

```
{
    "name": "Bagde",
    "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436053/chrome-extension-onclick-with-popup",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Hi",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

#### background.js

Used your code and eliminated conflicting `browserAction.onClicked` Event

```
var i = 1;

function updateIcon() {
    i = 1;
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: ''
    });
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
        popup: "popup.html"
    });
}


chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({
    color: [200, 0, 0, 100]
});

window.setInterval(function () {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: String(i)
    });
    i++;
}, 4000);
```

#### popup.html

Some trivial Page, used `popup.js` to comply with CSP.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Some Content ..</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

#### popup.js

Invoked Background Page function, so counter starts when ever icon is clicked

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    //Get Reference to Functions
    backGround = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    //Call Function
    backGround.updateIcon();
});
```

Comment: Hi Sudarshan, thanx for your answer. 

I dont want to stop badge, i just want to decrease to zero or empty string when i click to icon.

Besides i want to show my popup page, i know it makes conflict but how can i handle it?

Comment: Eliminate `browserAction.onClicked.addListener` in your code and use message passing to start trigger

Comment: @MuratCihan: Check **EDIT 1** of my answer , i have added a working version, hope it helps

Comment: The background page's `window` object is quite big, so I would send messages instead of using `getBackgroundPage()` if you can.